# What is the benefit of disabling dual-issue functionality on a ARM Cortex M7 processor?

Tags: arm, stm32

The Cortex M7 provides the possibility to disable dual-issue.

I understand the benefit of dual issue functionality but I don't really see the drawback.

Are there some programs that are more efficient without dual issue ? (perhaps programs withe many branches ?)

Is it linked to power consumption ?

Comment: Detailed documantation is not available.

Comment: Performancewise, I don't think there's any benefit, only drawbacks. Branch prediction would still exist due to pipelining. **Power** consumption might improve (i.e. the max mA/mW), but on the other hand, **energy** consumption (i.e. mAh/mWh consumed for a task for a battery powered application) might suffer in a properly designed program, since it would take longer to race back to sleep mode.

Comment: @swineone I beliewe it is only used if IC implementation has some issues

Answer (score 0):

Answer from an expert of ARM architectures: disabling dual-issue might be used (among other solutions) when the processor is overheating. Less transistors are used.